# потеря точности при вычитании близких float значений

Tags: python, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть простенькая программа для вычисления производной функции в точке:

```
from math import *  
x = float(input('x= '))  
d = float(input('d= '))  
def fi(x):  
    return x  
y = (fi(x+d/2)-fi(x-d/2))/d  
print 'Y`` in point =',y,
```

где d - приращение функции. При d стремится к 0 по определению мы получаем точный ответ. Например, при d = 0.001 ответ точнее чем при d = 0.1. Однако, если ввести очень маленькое d, например 10^(-15), то ответ получается кривой с погрешностью до 100%. Хотя должен давать точность в несколько десятков знаков после запятой. Из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: `например 10^(-15), то ответ получается кривой с погрешностью до 100%` можете пример привести? И еще, зачем `fi` если смысла в нем нет?

Comment: Ваш код всегда выдает 1.0. Какой смысл в fi(x)?

Comment: @Эникейщик попробуйте ввести например x 10 и d 0.00000000001 и ответ будет с погрешностью. fi очевидно чтобы работало для разных функций.

Comment: Причина погрешности лежит в двоичном представлении чисел. Ключевые слова - "float arithmetic broken".

Comment: @Эникейщик а можно попроще?) То есть это ограничение самого пайтона?

Comment: Нет, это ограничение двоичного представления чисел. Невозможно точно записать 0.1, 0.001 и 100500 других чисел в двоичной системе.

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо, а если мне нужна точность, например, в 40 знаков после запятой, как это реализовать?

Comment: Задать отдельный вопрос :) Но для начала поискать, тут наверняка уже есть ответ.

Comment: PS. Чисто для иллюстрации: выполните ``1.1+2.2``

Comment: @KAS, посмотрите в сторону класса Decimal, он для таких вещей и создавался

Answer (score 1):

Действительные числа часто представляются на компьютере с помощью [чисел с плавающей точкой (float)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9). Можно думать как о числах, записанных в научной нотации с использованием фиксированного количества цифр `p`: ±d.ddd...d×β<sup>e</sup>.

Относительная ошибка при вычислении разницы может достигать β-1. См. теорему 1 в [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

К примеру, если двоичная система используется (`sys.float_info.radix == 2`), то относительная ошибка может быть равна `1` (то есть все цифры в результате могут быть неверны), что вы и наблюдаете.