# Число округляется через раз toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть вот такая функция в React:

```
export const getTotalPrice = state =>{
        let totalPrice = 0
        state.basket.map((item) => totalPrice = totalPrice +  parseFloat(item.price.toFixed(2)) )
        return totalPrice
    }
```

По сути я из корзины `state.basket` узнаю полную стоимость заказа прибавляя каждый раз `item.price` в переменную `totalPrice` , числа все `ХХ.99`, в данном случае `139.99`, нажимая на кнопку добавить еще один такой элемент стоимость заказа пересчитывается и в результате сложив 13 раз число `139.99` я получаю `$1819.8700000000001`.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы все делаете (почти) правильно. Это техническое ограничение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829647/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-float-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment1325115_829647

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667706/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b3%d0%b8-float-double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно `toFixed()` применять к результату

```
totalPrice = (totalPrice + parseFloat(item.price)).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: получается ошибка, скорее всего несовпадение типов. Но вы мне подсказали верное решение, теперь я округляю не во время прохода по массиву, а когда делаю `return totalPrice.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку в двоичной системе невозможно точно представить овердофига дробных чисел, то цены лучше хранить в копейках (-> целые числа) и форматировать при выводе (разделив на 100). Тогда можно сколько угодно раз складывать что угодно и результат всегда будет верным.